# How is the Mathematica kernel structured internally, and how does evaluation work?

Tags: evaluation, kernel

There is so much information available for Java--the internal details of (for example) the JVM memory manager are well-documented, and the performance considerations arising from its interaction with user code have been publicly discussed. I am interested to know if there is any comparable documentation for the *Mathematica* kernel. Specifically:

- What are the major steps involved in evaluation?
- Which of these are the most important from a performance standpoint?

Is there any public documentation available about how all of this is implemented? If there is, I wasn't able to find it after searching the Internet: neither the mechanics of the evaluation process, nor the internal workings of particular functions, seem to be known outside of WRI.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau,in that link also,that guys mentioning upto `Head`of the function evaluation.but where that `Head` will evaluate.I want to in-depth concept.like,If we evaluate any function,which component(`Kernel`) takes the important roles at the execution time.like,if you evaluate more `expressions` at a time,how that components(`Kernel`)gives the priorities to the `Expression's`.

Comment: It does mention evaluating elements (subexpressions) "in turn".

Comment: @Oleksandr R. quite the edit!

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15507/mathematica-as-a-normal-programming-language).

Comment: See if you can find a copy of  book _Power Programming With Mathematica: The Kernel_ by David B. Wagner, McGraw-Hill, 1996, in a library. It's out-of-print and hard to find, unfortunately, but it contains the best description I know of on how the kernel works.

Comment: @OleksandrR. And I thought I was the most radical editor on this site. But now I've met my master and I salute you.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Seeing your work I feel it should be possible to upvote edits.

Comment: @Nasser That thing is more than TEN years old! :D

Comment: [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/what-is-the-complete-sequence-of-evaluations-transformations-from-submitting-a-c) may also be (somewhat) relevant.

Comment: @all,see the following link, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html   in that,documentation was very clear,I think everyone easily understand.I want that type of documentation,if you read the above documentation,all the topics are interlinked.If you want to cover any topic,automatically you cover all the topics.                    you mentioned all the books links,that all are very expensive.is there any free documentation's?

Comment: @Nasser I know, but I wonder why there aren't newer rewrites

Answer (score 9):

To give references to the first part of your question:

The best description about the main evaluation loop I have ever read can be found in (as already stated in the comments) [Power Programming with Mathematica: The Kernel by David Wagner](http://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=3788). A free pdf version of this book can be [downloaded here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kllwg6y44p8va5g/Wagner%20All%20Parts-RC.pdf). Therein, he refers to the tutorial [Mathematica Internals: A Tutorial by David Withoff](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4683/).

Although, these documents are rather old, I'm pretty sure they are still correct since this topic covers the core evaluation process which hasn't changed.

Comment: Is there an alternative version of Withoff's article? I cannot open the postscript in the provided link, (I tried with many linux programs).

Comment: Also a fresh link for the book http://data.wolframmathematica.ru/working-files/WolframTechnologyCollection/books_mathematica/Power_Programming_with_Mathematica_The_Kernel.pdf (it is supposedly public domain now)