# what does Out store?

Tags: notebooks

I think the following can only be tested in a notebook. (Please correct me if not.)

```
Clear[a, b, c, d]
mA = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
mfA = MatrixForm[mA]
Head[Out[]]   (* List *)
Head[mfA]     (* MatrixForm *)
```

So `Out[]` is storing something other than the value of the previous expression.  I probably should not have been surprised, since this is evident in the notebook by examining the output line.  (In version 11 anyway; I do not recall whether this was true in previous versions.)  Similarly, `TableForm` stores in `Out[]` only its first argument  However, this wrapper stripping is not true of all forms.  For example, after evaluation of a `StringForm` we find that `Out[]` stores a `StringForm`, not a `String`.

My question: what rule governs the value of `Out[]`?

Comment: Same behavior in v8.0.4 and v9.0.1.

Comment: Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11370/3066

Comment: @xzczd. I think this behavior has been in the main loop evaluation cycle all the way back to V1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value stored in `Out` is, as a rule, what is displayed in the output. The only exception from that are the various `*Form`s, `MatrixForm` being an example of that. When one of such "wrappers" (as the [help](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm.html) calls it) is detected in the top level of the output, it is removed from the expression prior to assigning to `Out`. The front end makes it clear that what's displayed is not the value of `Out`:

> ```
> In[1]:= {{1,2},{0,1}} // MatrixForm
>
> Out[1]//MatrixForm= 1   2
>          ^^^^^^^^^^    
>                      0   1
>
> In[2]:= Out[1]
>
> Out[2]= {{1, 2}, {0, 1}}
> ```

The reason for this is that it's convenient for further processing of the output. The `MatrixForm` itself would be inoperable:

> ```
> In[3]:= ({{1,2},{0,1}} // MatrixForm) * 2
>
> Out[3]= 2 1   2
>
>            0   1
> ```

One would need to manually remove the outer layer every time of using `Out[]` as the price for wanting to have the output nicely displayed. So Mathematica does that for the user as a convenience.

In your example you assigned `MatrixForm[mA]` to `mfA` so that's what `mfA` is. (This is often exactly the undesirable behaviour.) As a *result* of the assignment, `MatrixForm[mA]` is printed. But now the rule gets applied, the top-level `MatrixForm` is shaved, and only `mA` stored in `Out` for that input line.

---

**Update:** the list of functions which behave as wrappers is `$OutputForms`, as found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51968/6041):

> `? $OutputForms`
>
> `$OutputForms` is a list of the formatting functions that get stripped off when wrapped around the output.

You can unprotect it, add or remove some (or all of them) and cause `MatrixForm` to be stored in the `Out` or `StringForm` not to:

```
In[1]:= Unprotect[$OutputForms];                                                

In[2]:= $OutputForms = {StringForm};                                            

In[3]:= {{1,2},{0,1}} // MatrixForm                                             

Out[3]= 1   2

         0   1

In[4]:= % + 2                                                                   

Out[4]= 2 + 1   2

             0   1

In[5]:= "abc" // StringForm                                                     

Out[5]//StringForm= abc
         ^^^^^^^^^^

In[6]:= Head[%]                                                                 

Out[6]= String
```

Comment: Yes, as I said in the original question, "this is evident in the notebook by examining the output line".  And I agree with your description, which is also discussed in my original question.  I also agree that wrapper stripping offers a certain convenience, although `mfA[[1]]` is explicit and not tiresome.  In fact, when the wrapper is stripped, it looks to me like the rule is to use the first part of the form.
My question: is there a **rule** that allows me to predict that `TableForm` will be stripped but not `SringForm`?  Or just "usefulness" as determined by Wolfram?

Comment: @Alan Seems I misunderstood. I've always thought it was a property of all the `*Form`s but it's not. Good catch. I'll do more research.

Comment: @Alan How about this? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51968/6041

Comment: Yes!  While that does not provide a "rule", it does pin it down concretely.  Thanks!

Comment: @TheVee : I believe another exception to your rule is when `$PrePrint` is used since, quoting from the help documentation, "$PrePrint is applied after Out[n] is assigned, but before the output result is printed."

Answer (score 7):

You should look at `Out`'s down-values. Here is what I get.

[image: out]

You can see the `Out` is essentially an indexed variable with assignments.

#### Update

`Out[ ]` is equivalent to

```
Out[Length[DownValues[Out]]]
```

#### Update 2

OK, lets look at the code exactly as you wrote it.

[image: out2]

In this case, `Out[3]` has its `MatrixForm` wrapper stripped off, so it is the same as `Out[2]`. This is explained in this [Documentation Center article](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframSystemSessions.html) in the section **The Main Loop**. So what you see is entirely as expected. My example where the assignment to `mfA` was followed by `;` is more interesting. In this case the special rule for `;` is invoked and that rule apparently does ***not*** strip off wrappers.

Comment: Yes, but that just pushes the question back a level: what is the assignment rule? (Btw, you can a different result because of your extra semicolon.)

Comment: @Alan. The assignment rules are shown in the down-values.

Comment: @Alan. For the effect of `;`, see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/3066)

Comment: No, what is show in the downvalues is only what is assigned as down values.  My question is exactly about this: what is the rule for creating down values for `Out`?  Either I am completely missing your point, or you have not yet responded to that question.  Btw, I pointed out the effect of the semicolon because your example does not display the problem that is at the core of my question; see my example in the original question.