# Interpreting traditional math

Tags: conversion, function-comparison

There are two ways (afaik) to parse traditional math string to an expression:

```
toExpr = ToExpression[#, TraditionalForm] &
interpreter = Interpreter["MathExpression"]
```

The former is faster but less capable.
I would like to know what are the differences between those approaches because I would like to avoid `Interpreter` unless I have to use it.

For a start:

```
toExpr@"sin^(-1)(x)"
interpreter@"sin^(-1)(x)"
```

> `x/sin`

> `ArcSin[x]`

```
toExpr["x(x)"]
interpreter["x(x)"]
```

> `x[x]`

> `x^2`

I would like to know other similar differences.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134081/1871

Comment: I don't think you'll ever get there with these tools. Traditional math is a mess of inconsistent notations that are highly context-dependent. For example, $1/ax$ means `1/(a*x)`, `(1/a)*x`, or `1/ax` depending on the mood of the author and the field of study (math, physics, econ, etc.). $sin^{-1}x$ means `ArcSin[x]` or `1/Sin[x]` depending on relative humidity. As you show below, $a=b$ means `a==b` or `a=b` depending on context. There's lots of experience, intuition, and fault-tolerance going into parsing real math written by real people.

Comment: @Roman You certainly can't get everywhere but you can get somewhere and it is good to know where exactly. My use case allows me to require reasonable conventions from 'input source' plus I can tweak the input if needed. I just want to have a robust, even if limited, tool.

Comment: I wonder if the test suite in the answer(s) is likely to become quite large, random, and lacking structure. Examples: `"sin t^2"`/`"sin t^(2)"`/`"sin t^(-1)"`, `"f^(-1)(x)"`, `"sin^(-2)(x)"`

Answer (score 3):

*under construction, feel free to contribute*

*examples in form of `input => toExpr[input] | interpreter[input]`*

1. `ToExpression` does not parse **`"e"`** as `E`.
2. `ToExpression` does not parse **`"sqrt"`** as `Sqrt`

   ```
   "sqrt(e)"  =>  sqrt[e] | Sqrt[E]
   ```
3. `ToExpression` does not understand **inverse function notation**

   ```
   "sin^(-1)(x)" =>   x/sin | Arcsin[x]
   ```
4. `ToExpression` is strict about requiring **multiplication operator in ambiguous cases**:

   ```
   "x(x)" =>  x[x]  | x^2
   ```

   But it is better to be consistent:

   ```
   "y(y(x)+x)" =>  y[x + y[x]] | y (x + y[x])
   ```
5. `ToExpression` is strict about `* vs .` wrt **matrix multiplication**. It parses `*` as elementwise multiplication.

   ```
   "{{2,2}}*{{2},{3}}" => {{2, 2}} {{2}, {3}} (*+msg*)    | {{10}}
   ```
6. `Interpreter` is picky about **case and symbol names** in general

   ```
   "x+C" => x+C | Failure[..]
   ```

   This is likely a feature and was already reported.
7. `ToExpression` is strict about `=` vs. `==`. `Interpreter` parses `=` as `==`.

   ```
   "f(x) = x^2"  => x^2 | f[x]==x^2
   ```

   Notice how the former set `f[x]` definition so interpreter would return `True` if evaluated in the same session as `f[x] == x^2` would return `True`.

   Anticipating `=` you can use `ToExpression[_, TraditionalForm, Hold] /. Set -> Equal`